# Returning a tuple in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7, swift

sorry for such a basic question but I ve only just started working with tuples

this is my code

```
func test() -> (authorName:String, numberOfViews:Int) {

    let author : String = ""
    let numberViews = 0


    return(authorName : author, numberOfView : numberViews)


}
```

can anyone provide the correct way to do this

thanks in advance

Comment: You just have a typo. In your `return` statement, `numberOfView` should be `numberOfViews`. (Typically you'd also put a space between the `return` and the `(`)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

according to the Apple's swift book:

```
func test() -> (authorName:String, numberOfViews:Int) {

let author : String = ""
let numberViews = 0


return(author, numberViews)
}
```

you define the return object at the declaration. and in the return statement just put the values.

Comment: But `return (authorName: author, numberOfViews: numberViews)` works as well.

Answer (score 0):

For create a tuple simply put it in normal brackets and separate each other with comas, you also can do it on te return function
Example :
`let exampleTuple = (23, "A string", 5.583)`

The article from Apple :

Tuples group multiple values into a single compound value. The values within a tuple can be of any type and do not have to be of the same type as each other.In this example, (404, "Not Found") is a tuple that describes an HTTP status code. An HTTP status code is a special value returned by a web server whenever you request a web page. A status code of 404 Not Found is returned if you request a webpage that doesn’t exist.

`let http404Error = (404, "Not Found")`